# Groupbox foreach not finding all textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to find which textbox i have entered the information into on a form and make the rest of the textboxes within the form blanked out and locked so no information can be entered into them.

The problem is when i run the code and debug. I do not seem to be finding all the textboxes that are on the form when looping through them.

I have tried to change some of the information in the foreach by trying to find if groupbox name.equals and if items within groupbox equal text. I assume i have made mistake with the foreach statements.

Below is my code.

```
 foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
            {
                if (C is GroupBox)

                    foreach (Control T in this.Controls)
                    {
                        if (T is TextBox)
                        {
                            {
                                if (T.Text != string.Empty && T.Name.Equals("txtlotno"))
                                {
                                    txtheads.Enabled = false;
                                    txtheads.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    GroupBoxHeads.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
                                    txtrisersgood.Enabled = false;
                                    txtrisersgood.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    GroupBoxRisers.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
                                }

                                else if (T.Text != string.Empty && T.Name.Equals("txtvingot"))
                                {
                                    txtheads.Enabled = false;
                                    txtheads.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    GroupBoxHeads.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
                                    txtrisersgood.Enabled = false;
                                    txtrisersgood.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    GroupBoxRisers.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
                                }
                                else if (T.Text != string.Empty && T.Name.Equals("txtheads"))
                                {
                                    txtvingot.Enabled = false;
                                    txtvingot.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    txtlotno.Enabled = false;
                                    txtlotno.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    GroupBoxIngot.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
                                    txtrisersgood.Enabled = false;
                                    txtrisersgood.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    GroupBoxRisers.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
                                }
                                else if (T.Text != string.Empty && T.Name.Equals("txtrisersgood"))
                                {
                                    txtvingot.Enabled = false;
                                    txtvingot.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    txtlotno.Enabled = false;
                                    txtlotno.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    GroupBoxHeads.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
                                    txtheads.Enabled = false;
                                    txtheads.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                                    GroupBoxIngot.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple error in your loop initialization

```
foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
{
     if (C is GroupBox)
     {
        foreach (Control T in C.Controls)
        {

         ......
```

The second foreach should work on the controls of the groupbox not again on `this.Controls`.
Of course, these loops works only for TextBoxes contained in a GroupBox. If you have a TextBox outside of any GroupBox this code will not find them-

However, why do you need a loop?
You change a finite number of textboxes, so you could just access the textboxes directly

```
 if (txtlotno.Text != string.Empty)
 {
     txtheads.Enabled = false;
     txtheads.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
     GroupBoxHeads.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
     txtrisersgood.Enabled = false;
     txtrisersgood.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
     GroupBoxRisers.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
 }
 .... and so on the the other three
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be that you are iterating through this.Controls and not the controls in your groupbox

However, the loop seems redundant, since you directly access each Textbox by name. I would maybe try something like this:

```
List<TextBox> _disable = new List<TextBox>(); 
List<TextBox _enable = new List<TextBox>(); 

// Gather Textboxes to be disabled and enabled 
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
    GroupBox group = c as GroupBox; 
    if(group == null ) // Not a group box so continue on 
        continue; 
    foreach(Control c in group.Controls)
    {
        TextBox tb = c as TextBox; 
        if(tb == null )
           continue; // Not a textbox so continue on 

        if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(tb.Text)) // We have information so add to _enable
           _enable.Add(tb); 
        else 
           _disable.Add(tb); // empty textbox so ... disable 
    }
}

// Enable or Disable Textboxes 
foreach(TextBox tb in _enable)
{
   tb.Enabled = true; 
   tb.BackColor = Colors.White
}

foreach(TextBox tb in _disable)
{
   tb.Enabled = false; 
   tb.BackColor = Colors.LightGrey 
}
```

This approach lets you Loop through all your group boxes, loop through all their textboxes and organize each textbox and enable/disable them together, or not disable any if the _enable list is empty.  Alternatively, instead of adding them to a list, you could just disable them/enable them right there.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to iterate through the Controls of the GroupBox:

```
foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
        {
            if (C is GroupBox)

                foreach (Control T in C.Controls) // loop GroupBox controls
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF I am using the following procedure in order to get all TextBox Controls in main Grid and its nested containers. The same approach should work in your case as well.

```
private List<TextBox> GetTB(Grid Grd)
{
    List<TextBox> _lstT = new List<TextBox>();
    try
    {
        // get ALL TextBox in main Grid and sub Grid/UniformGrid
        UIElementCollection _mainGrd = Grd.Children;
        foreach (UIElement el in _mainGrd)
        {
            if (el is TextBox) { _lstT.Add((TextBox)el); }
            else if (el is Grid)
            {
                foreach (UIElement el1 in ((Grid)el).Children)
                { if (el1 is TextBox) { _lstT.Add((TextBox)el1); } }
            }
            else if (el is UniformGrid)
            {
                foreach (UIElement el1 in ((UniformGrid)el).Children)
                { if (el1 is TextBox) { _lstT.Add((TextBox)el1); } }
            }
        }
        return _lstT;
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```